# i dont want to display comma after displaying last value

Tags: php

Display comma after displaying last value:

```
$len = count($boltpatterns);
foreach ($boltpatterns as $key => $boltpattern) {

    $st1=$boltpattern['BP'];
    $st2='-';
    $pos=strpos($st1,$st2);

    if($pos === false){

    } else {
        echo $st1;
        if($key != $len - 1) {
            echo ',';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> You could have simply used [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function.

array_column() lists all your 'BP' keys into one single dimensional array.

implode() converts this single dimensional array $arr into string, separating each entry with a comma.

```
$arr = array_column($boltpatterns, 'BP');

echo implode(',', $arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new variable that will keep track of how many items you have looped through.

```
$len = count($boltpatterns);
$count = 1;
foreach ($boltpatterns as $key => $boltpattern) {
    $st1=$boltpattern['BP'];
    $st2='-';
    $pos=strpos($st1,$st2);
    if($pos === false){

    } else {
        echo $st1;
        if($count != $len) {
            echo ',';
        }
    }
    ++$count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like this,

```
$valid_data = array();
foreach ($boltpatterns as $key => $boltpattern) {
    if ( false !== strpos($boltpattern['BP'],'-') ){
        $valid_data[] = $boltpattern['BP'];
    }
}
echo implode(", ", $valid_data);
```

Explanation: Here we collect all the valid date we need to display to a new array. And we use PHP inbuilt function to display them.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array_column($boltpatterns, 'BP');

echo rtrim(implode(', ', $arr), ', ');
```

This is an improved version of @object-manipulator's code, with rtrim removing the trailing comma.